# "Adapter" for member variables

Tags: c++, adapter

Typically the purpose of an adapter is to make function calls in a modified format. Is there any way to do the same sort of thing for member variables? That is, say I have an object that contains a `SomePoint` and another object that contains a `DifferentPoint`. `SomePoint` stores it's data as member variables capitalized `X` and `Y` where `AnotherPoint` stores it's data as member variables lowercase `x` and `x`. So the problem is that you can't write a function that accepts either a `SomePoint` or a `DifferentPoint` because you can't access `.x` or `.X` (even using templates without specializing entirely for each different point type, in which case you might as well just overload on the point type).

The question is is there a way to make an adapter that will produce `.X` for a `SomePoint` when `.x` is requested? Both of these point types are library classes, so I can't edit the internals of either one directly. I would also like to avoid copying the data.

Comment: I'm confused as to how this problem would be fundamentally different if you were dealing with member functions `getx()` and `getX()`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You could then just change the implementation of the function in an adapter to return the correct value (you could have one adapter per Point class).

Comment: Why not write such an adapter function for the member variable, then? Something like `int getX(SomePoint const&)` and `int getX(DifferentPoint const&)`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Because I want one to act like the other, mainly so I can pass them both to an existing library function that I cannot change.

Answer (score 9):

The usual way to do this is to write a traits class to specify how to get out the data you want.

Here's a possible implementation using pointer-to-members. You could make them into functions or lambdas if you would rather.

```
template <typename T>
struct PointTraits;

template <>
struct PointTraits<SomePoint> {
    constexpr static auto getX = &SomePoint::x;
    constexpr static auto getY = &SomePoint::y;
};

template <>
struct PointTraits<AnotherPoint> {
    constexpr static auto getX = &AnotherPoint::X;
    constexpr static auto getY = &AnotherPoint::Y;
};
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
template <typename PointT>
void printX (const PointT& point) {
    std::cout << point.*PointTraits<T>::getX;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on what TartanLlama said, you could use a free function akin to `std::tuple` and its get<>.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct SomePoint { double x; double y; };

namespace adapter
{

template <typename T>
struct PointTraits;

template <>
struct PointTraits<SomePoint> {
    constexpr static auto getters = std::make_tuple(&SomePoint::x, &SomePoint::y);
};

const unsigned X = 0;
const unsigned Y = 1;
template<
  unsigned C, class Point,
  class Traits = PointTraits<
                  std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<Point>>
                 >
>
constexpr decltype(auto) get (Point&& p)
{
    return std::forward<Point>(p).*(std::get<C>(Traits::getters));
}

}

int main()
{
    using namespace adapter;
    SomePoint sp {1, 2};

    std::cout << get<X>(sp) << '\n'
              << get<Y>(sp) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an adapter class `Point` which has implicit conversion syntax for both of the target types. **Note** it requires that the data is copied, so not ideal:

```
class Point {
    XType x;
    YType y;
public:
    Point (const SomePoint& orig) : x(orig.X), y(orig.Y){}
    Point (const DifferentPoint& orig) : x(orig.x), y(orig.y){}

    XType getX(){return x;};
    YType getY(){return y;};
}
```

It's not ideal but if you cannot access the internals of the other two classes then this is a potential solution. Of course I've assumed that your `X` and `Y` were the same time as `x` and `y`...

Use then is

```
void printX (const Point& point) {
     std::cout << point.getX();
}
...
SomePoint origin(0,0);
printX(Point{origin});
```

TartanLlama's solution above is more flexible though, allowing various types of X and Y.

Comment: This also copies all of the data. I did not mention it in the question (I will edit) but I want to avoid copying all of the data.

Comment: Sorry. I will add a little caveat at the top to indicate that this requirement is not fulfilled in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to inherit publicly from one of the 'offenders' and introduce a reference to the differently named member. I believe it's less typing and more convebnient to use than both adaptor and traits mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: This is not an option when you're using already created classes, for example, library classes.

Comment: @EdwinRodríguez, why? I see no problem with that.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you said